# How to lookup a type used in a module by name in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

In LLVM, it is possible to lookup a function by name within a module using `Function* Module::getFunction(StringRef Name) const`.

Similarly, it is possible to lookup a global variable by name within a module using `GlobalVariable* Module::getGlobalVariable(StringRef Name) const`.

How can I do the same thing with a type defined within a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types are different from Functions and global variables because those two exist within a Module, and are things that will eventually have some bytes in the executable or whatever is generated. Types aren't like that.

Types occupy no space, exist within the [Context](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LLVMContext.html) and aren't necessarily findable. They generally can be found, though: If you want to find the singleton 42-bit integer type, you ask [IntegerType::get()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IntegerType.html#a14f7b4f1aed38192fb6b7772eb506bdb), and if you want to find a struct, you ask StructType, either [by structure](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StructType.html#a18fc4545474c6ebb6f7c547f64f4fb31) or [by name](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StructType.html#a75a89f1513d9f9bdcf0366a436ca43b5).

(Keep in mind that not every struct type can be found by asking LLVM. In my case, I once had a problem where a caller needed to make a pointer to a struct, but the struct type was still just a placeholder at that point in the code, without either a name or a definition. I ended up finding the right LLVM type by asking my own code, rather than by asking LLVM, and I think many people do similar things.)

Answer (score 0):

`StructType *StructType::getTypeByName(Context, Name)`. If you don't have a Context, use `MyModule.getContext()`. [doxygen](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StructType.html#a75a89f1513d9f9bdcf0366a436ca43b5)

Offhand I don't think other types can have names.

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement

> ... a type defined within a module

could only apply to identified structs because there can only be a single identified struct with a given name in a particular LLVMContext. Literal struct types are uniqued structurally and primitives like an `i8` already sought of 'exist', so all you do is get them and use them to annotate values. Maybe that's why they're created with a `get` method.

You can get the identified structs in an `llvm::Module` using the [Module::getIdentifiedStructTypes](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a8c7aeef16441f671e5e541a4f3eda0c5) method.

If walking over a module and identifying all the types used in that module is something that interests you, definitely have a look at [TypeFinder.cpp](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-703.0.31/src/lib/IR/TypeFinder.cpp.auto.html)